# How CLR knows type of [unboxed] Value Type variable at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Since [in unboxed state] `value type` object is placed in stack and doesn't contain reference to its `Type`, how CLR knows it at runtime?
Is there some kind of table with that info for all variables managed by CLR?

Thanks!

Comment: In what context are you thinking that the CLR *needs* to know about the type?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, e.g. when CLR boxing this variable it needs to put type handle in resulted boxed object

Comment: It doesn't know, it is only interested in objects.  The code knows, it contains load and store instructions that are specific to the value type.  And the jitter takes advantage of this by *not* using the stack for storage if it can, processor registers are quite a bit faster.  One easy to see side-effect of this lack of knowledge is that Reflection cannot give you any info about local variables.

Comment: When the compiler emits a box instruction, it has to include the correct type token at that point.

Comment: So, there are no runtime checks and _work behing the scene_ by CLR, because all info is provided by generated code at compile time? Cool!

Comment: @HansPassant Shouldn't that be an answer and not a comment?

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis I think that what Damien wrote is more important. The il-code instruction `box` has as  a "parameter" the unboxed type.

Comment: See for example: http://goo.gl/yAh5WV: *box [mscorlib]System.Int32*